# how to configure eclipse run configurations for System Properties (ssl/tls) in command line arguments

Tags: java, eclipse, ssl, command-line-arguments

My command line input is when I run without IDE,  java -

```
Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore="d:/xxxLS/xxxx.jks" 
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=posclient 
pDevice.ClientMain 1 d:/xxxLS/xxsSslxxxClient.jks 
possslandencryptclient possslclient posencryptclient localhost 7866 SslYes EncYes
```

When I try to run the application in Eclipse, it not works. How to specify SSL/TLS key path in Eclipse. I have key files in my disk.(xxxx.jks,  xxsSslxxxClient.jks)

I don't know how to configure my eclipse for the specific command line arguments.
  file name (to be excecuted) `Device.ClientMain`

Please help me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, I got solution where to place the TLS/SSL keys in the eclipse Run -> Run Configurations -> under Main select the class which going to run, -> (X)Arguments provide the key details which you to include under the VM arguments,under Program Arguments pass the usual command line arguments. When running SSL layer client/server applications key list or key details should be included under the VM arguments. My program works well.

In Details, Arguments are divided into Program Arguments, VM arguments in Eclipse, Program arguments are arguments that are passed to your application, which are accessible via the "args" String array parameter of your main method. VM arguments are arguments such as System properties that are passed to the Java s w interpreter.

The VM arguments go after the call to your Java interpreter (ie, 'java') and before the Java class. Program arguments go after your Java class.

```
 Public class ArgsTest {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    System.out.println("Program Arguments:");
    for (String arg : args) {
        System.out.println("\t" + arg);
    }

    System.out.println("System Properties from VM Arguments");
    String sysProp1 = "sysProp1";
    System.out.println("\tName:" + sysProp1 + ", Value:" + System.getProperty(sysProp1));
    String sysProp2 = "sysProp2";
    System.out.println("\tName:" + sysProp2 + ", Value:" + System.getProperty(sysProp2));

}
```

}
Pass input as, java ArgsTest -DsysProp1=sp1 -DsysProp2=sp2  pro1 pro2 pro3

```
Output would be:
 Program Arguments:
pro1
pro2
pro3
 System Properties from VM Arguments
Name:sysProp1, Value:sp1
Name:sysProp2, Value:sp2
```